# How to prove a minimum number of queries needed to determine a piece of information

Tags: logic, information-theory, lower-bounds, entropy, karnaugh-map

> You have 27 coins, 1 of which is a different weight. Using a balance scale with 2 pans, how can you determine which coin is different in only 4 weighings?
>
> Generalize this to N coins.

#### Hint

> My solution was to number the coins in trinary and weigh them as follows:

#### Solution

> 1. Coins whose 1st trit is 0 on the left; coins whose 1st trit is 1 on the right
> 2. Coins whose 2nd trit is 0 on the left; coins whose 2nd trit is 1 on the right
> 3. Coins whose 3rd trit is 0 on the left; coins whose 3rd trit is 1 on the right
>
> If any of the weighings are balanced, we know the differing coin is in the 3rd group. We are then working with a much smaller number of coins and the problem simplifies.
>
> If all weighings are not balanced, this algorithm is equivalent to arranging the coins in a trinary (3×3×3) cube and then sorting the planes in each dimension: You move the coins that were on the heavy side to one side of the cube, the ones that were on the light side to the opposite, leaving the equal weight ones in the center.
>
> 4. After sorting, one corner of the cube will either be heavier or normal, while the opposite corner will be either lighter or normal. So you compare one corner to a reference coin to determine which corner is different.

#### Generalized solution

> For N coins, this argument generalizes using a trinary hypercube with $\lceil \log_3{N} \rceil + 1$ weighings.

However, this seems inefficient as it would imply you need 4 weighings for 10 coins.

## Is there a more systematic way?

Each weighing has 3 possible outcomes, so can yield a maximum of 1 trit of information, so the lower bound on the number of weighings is

$$ \lceil \log_3 27 \rceil = 3 $$

And if we want to find the differing coin *and* whether it is lighter or heavier, we need an extra bit of information, so we'll need a minimum of

$$ \lceil \log_3 \left( 27 \cdot 2 \right) \rceil = 4 $$

weighings. Which is the number of weighings my solution uses. Yet I struggled to prove that 4 is the minimum number of weighings required in general. To do so, I reasoned that none of the 27 possible results of 3 weighings can result in us learning whether the coin is lighter or heavier, or we will not have enough information left to discriminate between all 27 coins. But if we weigh the differing coin at any point, we will know if it is lighter or heavier, and we have no systematic way to avoid weighing it. Contradiction.

However, the entire line of reasoning above is very hand-wavy and also took a lot of time and cleverness to work out. Is there a more systematic way to find a [tight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upper_and_lower_bounds#Tight_bounds) lower bound for these kinds of problems involving information? Perhaps with something analogous to a [Karnaugh map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map)?